# Array Values in CGRect

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, cgrect

I have an array of coordinates, x and y like

> NSArray *objectCoords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                                @"{{116,371},{85,42}}",
>                                @"{{173,43},{85,42}}",
>                                @"{{145,200},{85,42}}",

I am trying to draw a circle using drawRect.like:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

   // [super drawRect:rect];  144,179,130
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor grayColor].CGColor);



    int x=10;
    int y=10;
    CGRect rectangle0;
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
     rectangle0 = CGRectMake(x,y,10,10);//just to draw
        x=x+20;
        y=y+23;
        NSLog(@"x: %d  and y: %d", x,y);
         CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle0);
    }
```

}

I am not sure, how to put these coordinates of array in the CGRect to draw circle at those particular coordinates.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Is it actually an array of strings? Did you try iterating over the array contents?

Comment: Why are you putting string representation of the rects in your array?

Comment: Thats the response from the server:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a CGRect object from a string representation using `CGRectFromString(string)`. This takes strings in the format `{{x,y},{w, h}}` (which thankfully your strings are!)

For example:

```
NSArray *objectCoords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"{{116,371},{85,42}}", @"{{173,43},{85,42}}", @"{{145,200},{85,42}}",

for (NSString* objectCoord in objectCoords) {
    CGRect coord = CGRectFromString(objectCoord);
    // Draw using your coord
}
```

Conversely, if you have a CGRect, you can get a string representation via `NSStringFromCGRect(rect)`

Comment: Another good way to serialize is with NSValue. `+[NSValue valueWithCGRect:]` and `-[NSValue CGRectValue]`.

Comment: Very good point. Personally, any internal storage of CGRects required to be an object should be `NSValue`. If you need to communicate to an external service (for whatever reason, JSON web service for example), the string representation works well here.

Comment: Yes, i m using a JSON to get the coordinates.That worked like a charm.thanks WDUK.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CGRectFromString` to convert such `NSString`s to `CGRect`s